# ServiceFabric - Primary Replication Queue Usage throeshold

Tags: queue, replication, azure-service-fabric

I'm facing this Warning message on a ServiceFabric cluster:

"Primary Replication Queue Usage of 95% has reached/exceeded the threshold 80%. First Replication Operation = 1818843, Last Replication Operation = 1826640"

When the partition is in this condition, every call to it from other services will stuck awaiting for the method return.

I've tried searching for this message meaning but with no success.
What does it mean and what may cause it?

Comment: What is happening in your code that might lead to this situation? are u putting a heavy load in the State Manager? Are you using reliable collections? we need some more info...

Comment: @RotemVaron what do you mean by "heavy load", writing frequency or State size?
Data are arriving from different EventHubs with a rate of 1 message each 3s from 100 senders, so I have to persist data (just the last message) at an avg of 33 times per second.
Service has 10 partition so the avg speed for each partition is about 3.3 writes/s.
If this is what you mean, I can guess an I/O limit.

Comment: ok, tnx for the additional info. I meant the frequency. I wonder if you run your system and reduce the number of writes substantially, will you still get this error? maybe use just one sender...

Comment: Thank you @RotemVaron, I can't reduce the senders but I've found the with a nodes upgrade the warning is no more happening.
Before I was using 5 Standard D2_V2 nodes, now I'm working with D3_V2.
But I still don't know what's the meaning behind that warning message: is there some sort of queue before the transaction get written down the disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve high availability, Service Fabric stateful services replicate their state to the configured target replica. Every time primary receives a write operation, it applies it locally and also sends it to the secondary replicas; it waits until a quorum of replicas ACK the operation before it returns back to the user.

As soon as the operation is ACKed by all replicas in the partition, the operation is removed from queue.

If the secondaries are slow to ACK, the primary queue fills up and then write operations are stalled. Read operations are not affected. In your case, the replication queue has operations with sequence number 1818843 to 1826640.

The reasons for so many operations in the queues could be: slow persist to disk on either primary or secondaries (due to slow disks, too much IO etc) or message delays from one or more secondaries that do not allow the primary to remove the operations from the queue.

Comment: Thank you Oana, finally an explanation to this message!